# Proxy-based change tracking, property not updated in POCO object

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, change-tracking

I'm using EF5 code-first with proxy-based changed tracking in my ASP.NET MVC application.
One of my domain classes contains a numeric property which is updated very frequently.  For this reason, this property is not persisted to the database using the framework:

```
public virtual int CurrentSessions
{
    get
    {
        return _currentSessions;
    } 

    set
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _currentSessions, value);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the value of the property is not updated across sessions.  My API controller either increases the above value or decreases it, according to internal logic, as follows:

```
myObj.CurrentSessions++;
```

or

```
myObj.CurrentSessions--;
```

where myObj is a proxied object retrieved from a context via LINQ in each session:

```
var myObj = objectContext.Instances<myPocoEntity>().FirstOrDefault(cb => cb.SomeProp == someValue);
```

When I inspect the value of myObj.CurrentSessions after it has been increased/decreased, it is indeed updated, but on the next server request, when myObj is retreived again, CurrentSessions has always its initial value, zero.

How can I make sure the property value is updated in the POCO entity without scanning the entire context for changes?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have separate DbContext objects and when one updates an object the other isn't seeing the changes until the next request for the object in the database?

If so, you may be able to reload the object in question via the DbEntityEntry class.

You could then either utilize the "Reload()" method or "GetDatabaseValues()" method to obtain the values that current exist in the database.

Example(s)

```
// Reload Usage
context.Entry(entity).Reload();


// GetDatabaseValues Usage
DbPropertyValues propertyValues = context.Entry(entity).GetDatabaseValues();
foreach (DbPropertyValue val in propertyValues)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll clarify: I'm talking about a **single** **ObjectContext** - not DbContext - entity (though there are many such different entities), which I'm updating across different ASP.NET MVC actions (think about multiple clients issuing "open" and "close" requests, which increment and decrement the counter accordingly.  My problem is the change to the counter value in one session is not reflected in the following session, accessing the same (yet proxied) counter property.